# Java Swing adding Action Listener for EXIT_ON_CLOSE

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

I have a simple GUI:

```
    public class MyGUI extends JFrame{

        public MyGUI(){
           run();
        }

        void run(){
           setSize(100, 100);
           setVisible(true);
           setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);// maybe an action listener here
        }
    }
```

I would like to print out this message:

```
 System.out.println("Closed");
```

When the GUI is closed (when the X is pressed). How can I do that?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try this.

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
    {
      System.out.println("Closed");
      e.getWindow().dispose();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility could be to override [`dispose()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose()) from the `Window` class. This reduces the number of messages sent around and also works if the default close operation is set to `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`.

Concretely this means adding

```
@Override
public void dispose() {
    System.out.println("Closed");
    super.dispose();
}
```

to your class `MyGUI`.

Note: don't forget to call `super.dispose()` as this releases the screen resources!

Answer (score 1):

Write this code within constructor of your **JFrame**:

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
this.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Uncomment following to open another window!");
        //MainPage m = new MainPage();
        //m.setVisible(true);
        e.getWindow().dispose();
        System.out.println("JFrame Closed!");
    }
});
```

Comment: this is so useful, it solves my problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Window Events:**
There is the complete program, hope it will help you.
public class FirstGUIApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Frame
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    //Title:setTitle()
    window.setTitle("First GUI App");
    //Size: setSize(width, height)
    window.setSize(600, 300);
    //Show: setVisible()
    window.setVisible(true);
    //Close
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            super.windowClosing(e); 
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are sure to close!");
        }

        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            super.windowOpened(e); 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to the System");
        }
        
    });
   
}
```

}