# How to do action when closing the frame?

Tags: java, database, netbeans, frame

How do I do action when I'm going to terminates the programme.

For example :

When I'm going to terminates the programme, I want to set

```
if( the x button is clicked or something )
deleteRow from database;
else
just end.
```

Is it should be done inside the ui frame ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295942/java-swing-adding-action-listener-for-exit-on-close

Comment: I can just add it on ui rite ?

Comment: see [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JFrameaddWindowListenerWindowListenerlis.htm) example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window listeners for that. `windowClosing` method is used to execute code when window is closing, `windowClosed` method can be used if you want to do something after the window has closed.

```
JFrame window=new JFrame("Window");
window.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
     @Override
     public void windowClosed(WindowEvent evt)
     {
         //Do something after window has closed.
     }
     public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt)
     {
         //Do something when window is closing.
         //Useful when you have to access data in window(buttons, textfields etc)
     }
});
```

There are also other window event listeners.[Documentation of WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
  addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
               .....

            }
        });
```

Comment: Is this your solution? If yes mark it as soon as possible and vote up other good answers.