# Frame closing command _variable

Tags: java

so, my first post.

I study Java. There I got an issue. I want to get a pop.up window open, when attempting to close a window 0 frame.

So, I insert this. From an example code of the teacher.
Check it out please
here it goes

```
private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
            int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Really close?", "Close?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                this.dispose();
            if (reply == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                this.setVisible(true);
            }
    }
```

It does nothing. no pop up window that gives me what is demanded

Comment: Are you sure the function is being called? A quick simple way to find this out would be to put a System.out.println at the start of the function.

Comment: When do you expect this method to be called? For better help sooner, please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Duplicate? : [Java Swing adding Action Listener for EXIT_ON_CLOSE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295942/java-swing-adding-action-listener-for-exit-on-close)

Answer (score 1):

Your method most likely won't ever be called. You need to use a WindowListener. Here is how you set it up:

```
JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame(); //that's your frame

mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE) //enable windowlistener handling

mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() { //you need to add a windowlistener

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            formWindowClosing(e); //call your method
        }

        @Override 
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}

        @Override 
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}

        @Override 
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}

        @Override 
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}

        @Override 
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}

        @Override 
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}

    });
```

This will call your closing method when your program requests to exit.

Comment: I really do not know where to add this, I tried but unsuccesfully. Sorry for the lack of knowledge. I might try once more and if do not confirm here, that it has worked, please assist me on that.

Comment: Add `setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)` after you created your JFrame. Add `addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {...});` right after that. (Probably in a constructor where you have a line like: `mainFrame = new JFrame("Title"); /*add code*/`.

Answer (score 0):

I use the NetBeans platform.
So my code is as follows:

```
package my.exercise21;
```

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class Exercise21 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/**
 * Creates new form Exercise21
 */
public Exercise21() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_X, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    jMenuItem1.setText("Exit");
    jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    dispose();
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
        int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Really close?", "Close?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            this.dispose();
        if (reply == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
}   

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Exercise21.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new Exercise21().setVisible(true);
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I guess my problem lies in not calling the JOptionPane library

Answer (score 0):

I have had just fixed the issue. Thank you for helpful participation and your kind inspiration.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package my.exercise21;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
*
* @author Administrator
*/
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Exercise 2.1");
    setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.NW_RESIZE_CURSOR));
    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            formWindowClosed(evt);
        }
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            formWindowClosing(evt);
        }
    });

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_X, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    jMenuItem1.setText("Exit");
    jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void formWindowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                 

private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
    int r = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Really close?", "Close?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (r == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            dispose(); // This closes the program
        if (r == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            setVisible(false); // This just hides the window but program keeps running.
    }// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                  

private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    dispose();        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}