# Using the exit button for executing a function

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a problem and don't find a solution.

I have two different forms created with Java Swing and if I click a Button on the first form, than the second form is `setVisible(true)` and the first form is `setVisible(false)`. 
When the user now clicks the X on the top right hand corner the second form should be disposed and the first form should `setVisible(true)`.

So how is it possible to execute code when clicking the X?

Comment: This could help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093448/how-to-capture-a-jframes-close-button-click-event

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding a actionListener to the X?

Like it's done here:
[Java Swing adding Action Listener for EXIT_ON_CLOSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295942/java-swing-adding-action-listener-for-exit-on-close)

Comment: Hello, thats it! Thank you very much!