# how to pass data from one class to another

Tags: java, class

I am struggling with two classes, my first class must receive data and store it in variables, the second class must send it to the first class.

My problem is that I am doing in the second class new first, which makes a new instance of the first class, and that's why I can't modify what I need.

For example:

```java
public class EditText extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    private String fontName = "Arial";
    private int fontStyle = 0;
    private int fontSize = 10;
    
    String filename = "Untitled";

    public EditText() {
        initComponents();
        getProperties();
        updateFont();
        JList lstFont = new javax.swing.JList(
                GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames());
    }
```

```java
public class FontWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {  
   
    private String fontName = "Arial";
    private int fontStyle = 0;
    private int fontSize = 10;
   
    final EditText form = (null);
    
    public FontWindow() {
        initComponents();
        displayFontList();
    }
```

`EditText` is the first class, and the second is `FontWindow`.

I have an event on closing second class where it must transfer data to the first, I tried by doing it by

```
EditText form = new EditText();
```

However it does not work, because when I set visible the form it shows a new one, But I need the last one.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show us what you're trying to set. But ... I think you need to create an instance of EditText in FontWindow, then set the variables of the former from the latter

Comment: @macedonboy, i have form 1 which is not dynamically created, and i have form 2, same, i want to pass data to form 1 to form 2, linking it, the find option from notepad this is what i am trying to do.

Comment: One way to do that would be to use a window listener for the window closing event. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295942/java-swing-adding-action-listener-for-exit-on-close)

Comment: Thank you, i did it by setting the variable as static global in netbeans. Also tried your method, works the same.